# PGsql : Grant every single right to a user on a schema

Tags: postgresql, rights

I can't figure out how to give every single right to a specific user, I want a user to have every single right on a schema:

- inserts, deletes, updates, selects, ... on existing tables

I have tried doing :

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA schema to "user";
    GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA schema to "local_518561";
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table schema.table to "user";
    GRANT ALL ON table schema.table to "user";
```

The querys return succesfull, but every time I use the other user I get insuffiecent permissions error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the sequences, if you do not give rights to the table AND the sequence (if any) than you cannot insert.

Answer (score 23):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON                  SCHEMA schema_name TO role_name;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA schema_name TO role_name;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO role_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a version of PostgreSQL < 9, you can use the following store procedures to manage permissions of tables and sequences:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grantTablesOfSchema (user VARCHAR,
   permissions VARCHAR, schema VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$body$
DECLARE
  regActual   RECORD;
  numTables   INTEGER;
BEGIN

   numTables := 0;

   FOR regActual IN
      SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = schema
   LOOP
      numTables := numTables + 1;

      EXECUTE 'GRANT ' || permissions || ' ON ' || schema || '.' || regActual.tablename || ' TO ' || user;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 'Tables: ' || numTables::VARCHAR;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grantSequencesOfSchema (user VARCHAR,
   permissions VARCHAR, database VARCHAR, schema VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$body$
DECLARE
   regActual       RECORD;
   numSequences    INTEGER;
BEGIN

   numSequences := 0;

   FOR regActual IN
      SELECT sequence_catalog, sequence_schema, sequence_name 
      FROM information_schema.sequences 
      WHERE sequence_catalog = database AND sequence_schema = schema
   LOOP
      numSequences := numSequences + 1;

      EXECUTE 'GRANT ' || permissions || ' ON ' || schema || '.' || regActual.sequence_name || ' TO ' || user;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 'Sequences: ' || numSequences::VARCHAR;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And a example of use:

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'user1@user1?user1';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database1 TO user1;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema1 TO user1;

SELECT * FROM grantTablesOfSchema ('user1', 'SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE', 'schema1');

SELECT * FROM grantSequencesOfSchema ('user1', 'ALL', 'database1', 'schema1');
```

If, on the contrary your version of PostgreSQL is >= 9:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO user1;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO user1;
```